# Android:Problem about ListView OnScrollListener

Tags: android, listview

everyone I have a problem about getting Data when I scroll the ListView. 
My code is here:

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(scrollState){
            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:{
                /*Show which num is picked */
                /*
                if(view.getChildCount()>=5){
                    mBusy = false;
                    int firstPos = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    int pos = firstPos+1;
                    mShowBtn.setText(((TextView)view.getChildAt(pos)).getText());       
                }
                */
                break;
            }
            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
                mBusy = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Note:The code in the quote in the SCROLL_STATE_IDLE case is wrong. Why?  And how can I get the state that there are enough items already "exist" and I can operate them ?

Thanks a lot first!@o@

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish here. Why are you using onScrollStateChange? If you give more information as to what you are trying to create, there may be a better way to do it.

Comment: @David : I'm sorry David.I'll try to explain my problem,excuse me for my poor english first~.~                                                          In my project I have a ListView which I use to show a list of numbers that will be picked later . I create my own adapter and set it to the listview, and then I add listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){/* Here I override the method OnScrollState() and get wrong !*/}). What I need is to pick the (firstVisible+2)th number,and the visibleCount is 5. I wonder if I've made it clear. Hope your answer soon! Thanks!